# How to run n98-magerun with Magento on Wampserver?

Tags: magento-enterprise, wamp

I am being asked to wipe the contents (cache) of linux specific locations within Magento on Wampserver/Windows using n98-magerun. How specifically do I run n98-magerun in this situation? Please be specific. Thank You.

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you mean with "Linux specific locations on Windows" but this is the command to flush the cache as it works on the windows command line in the Magento root directory:

```
php.exe n98-magerun.phar cache:flush
```

This is assuming that php.exe is in your PATH and n98-magerun.phar in the current directory. Adjust paths if needed.

Comment: Got it! As for the Linux comment I was told that there are Linux specific locations within Magento (not windows) that (given my situation) I should consider flushing using the n98-magerun tool. Whether that comment is accurate or not I do not know.